# Convergent in Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $H$ be Hilbert space for fixed $h \in H$. Define $L:H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be bounded linear functional by $L(x):=<x,h>$ , for any $x \in H$. If we have $<x_n , y> \rightarrow <x,y>$. Can we prove that $x_n \rightarrow x$, where $y \neq 0$.

Comment: What is the question? Convergence of the inner products does not imply convergence of $x_n,y_n$.

Comment: $x_n,x = v, y_n,y = w$ for $||v||,||w|| = 1$, $v \not = w$.

Comment: Have you considered $y=0$?

Comment: No, $y$ is a nonzero element.

Comment: Do you want that the convergence $\langle x_n,y\rangle\to\langle x,y\rangle$ holds for all $y$ (except $y=0$)?

Comment: The convergent only for a fixed element $y$ in $H$.

Comment: The same thing works if $H$ is dimension > 1 and $x_n,x$ are perpendicular to $y$ (Also your question is confusing; there is a $h$ fixed, and an $L$ defined, but they are not used)

Comment: The dimension already >1 .Can you give me some details.

Comment: What details do you want? Eg do you need me to define any words I used?

Comment: Sorry, The fixed $h$ is the same fixed $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample- let $y = (1,0)\in\mathbb R^2$ with the usual dot product and let $x_n$ be any sequence with 0 first coordinate.

More generally as long as $\dim H>1$, if $x_n,x \in \operatorname{span}\{y\}^\perp$ then all inner products are 0, no matter if $x_n$ converge or not.

Comment: That is good. In my question I have a linear functional as it defined and I got a sequence in the complex plane  as we say above. The question is in any conditions can I get the convergent in $H$?

Comment: The inner product against one fixed vector is very weak information. The only time you can guarantee convergence is when $x_n,x \in \operatorname{span}\{y\}$. @Abdallah